# Can you get a duplicate hash with params that are NOT a string or array, using keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a, b))?

Tags: solidity, security, hash, keccak

It's relatively common to confirm a msg.sender is pre-approved for some contract interaction by verifying a signed hash of their address and another parameter. For instance:

```
bytes32 checkHsh = keccak256(abi.encodepacked(msg.sender, someUint256));
```

The contract would then go on to recover the signer from a corresponding signed hash provided in the calldata.

The abi.encodePacked() function can produce duplicate hashes from variable length params (strings or variable length arrays) because it doesn't pad the args. e.g.

```
keccak256(abi.encodePacked('ban', 'ana')) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked('ba', 'nana'))
```

**Question:**
Is there any way to make a duplicate hash using abi.encodePacked() params that are NOT strings or variable length arrays?
i.e. can (_address, _uint256) args ever produce a duplicate hash?
what about two (_uint256, _uint256) args?

(I have a feeling there is probably something with the zero address, but is there anything else?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would say no. This is because both `uint256` and `address` have fixed lengths, unlike the other example you showed with strings where it's possible to change the string length.

To be more precise, an `address` variable has a fixed length of 20 bytes and a `uint256` variable has a fixed length of 32 bytes. Therefore, it is not possible to produce duplicate hashes since you are not able to change the variable sizes.